# Calling an event from another aspx

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I have the next doubt, I have an aspx page where I want to put a button and then I have another aspx page with another button which have this event when you click on it.  I want that when you put on the button from the another page this one calls to the event from the second page's button. How Can I do this?. This is the event:

```
 Protected Sub lnkEnviarDatosCliente_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles lnkEnviarDatosCliente.ServerClick
    Dim dtcEncuesta As New EncuestasDataContext
    Dim puntuacion As New PuntuacionCuestionEmpleado
    Dim participado As New Participacion
    Dim cuestiones As List(Of DatosEncuesta) = listadoCuestiones

    'Dim resultados = CType(sender.parent.parent.Controls.Item(2).controls.item(7), Grid).Rows.Count
    Dim resultados = CType(sender.parent.parent.controls.item(2).FindControl("gdgRespuestasNuevas"), Grid)
    'For n As Integer = 0 To resultados.Rows.Count - 1

    '    cuestiones.Item(n).IdCuestionEncuesta = CType(Repeater1.Controls.Item(2).Controls.Item(7).FindControl("gdgRespuestasNuevas"), Grid).DataKeys(n).Item("IdCuestionEncuesta")
    '    cuestiones.Item(n).Cuestion = CType(Repeater1.Controls.Item(2).Controls.Item(7).FindControl("gdgRespuestasNuevas"), Grid).DataKeys(n).Item("CuestionEncuesta")

    'Next

    Dim puntosMax As Integer = cuestiones.Count
    'Dim puntosMax As Integer = CType(Repeater1.Controls.Item(1).FindControl("gdgRespuestasNuevas"), Grid).Rows.Count

    'guarda la puntuación asignada
    For i As Integer = 0 To cuestiones.Count - 1
        'For i As Integer = 0 To CType(CType(sender, Grid).Parent.FindControl("gdgRespuestasNuevas"), Grid).Rows.Count - 1
        puntuacion = New PuntuacionCuestionEmpleado
        puntuacion.CodigoEmpleado = Me.IdEmpleado
        'puntuacion.CodigoCuestionEncuesta = CType(CType(sender, Grid).Parent.FindControl("gdgRespuestasNuevas"), Grid).DataKeys(i).Item("IdCuestionEncuesta")
        puntuacion.CodigoCuestionEncuesta = cuestiones.Item(i).IdCuestionEncuesta
        puntuacion.Puntuacion = puntosMax - i
        dtcEncuesta.PuntuacionCuestionEmpleado.InsertOnSubmit(puntuacion)
    Next
    'Comprueba si se ha cambiado la lista original (el grid original)
    Dim esOrdenOriginal As Boolean = OrdenOriginal()

    'guarda los datos de Participación
    participado = New Participacion

    If esOrdenOriginal Then 'True: Si no se ha modificado del original...
        participado.Participa = False
    Else
        participado.Participa = True
    End If
    participado.FechaHora = Now()
    participado.CodigoEmpleado = Me.IdEmpleado
    participado.CodigoEncuesta = lblDatoEncuesta.Text
    dtcEncuesta.Participacion.InsertOnSubmit(participado)

    dtcEncuesta.SubmitChanges()
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "CerrarEncuesta", "CerrarEncuesta();", True)

End Sub
```

This event is from enc.aspx and I want to put the button at index.aspx. This event is to send data from client to server. Any help?. Thanks

Comment: you can achieve that by redirecting to `enc.aspx` page with some `Session` and in page load of `enc.aspx` check for `Session` and call the event...

Comment: Can you put all of this logic in a function and have both button call the same function?